# Regex - replace special character that comes before an exact word

Tags: regex, replace, regexp-replace

I need to replace a character that comes before a given word with another character.

For an example, I need to replace "=" character that comes before "@AccountId" with "IS" in below SQL query.

```
SELECT
   [ID],
   [Name],
   [Address]
FROM [Users]
WHERE [ID] = @ID AND [Account ID] = @AccountId
```

> [Account ID] = @AccountId

After replacing it should look like below,

```
SELECT
   [ID],
   [Name],
   [Address]
FROM [Users]
WHERE [ID] = @ID AND [Account ID] IS @AccountId
```

> [Account ID] IS @AccountId

Does anyone have any ideas for a regular expression I could use to achieve this?

**Please don't get confused by the example. In the next steps the @AccountId will be replaced to `NULL`. So finally it will look like `[Account ID] IS NULL`

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? At least searched? Try a search with tag `[sed]`. Which OS?

Comment: It's in C# and I've already implemented a logic using C#. But just wondering if there are any easy ways to deal with this using Regular Expressions.

Comment: Why do you need regex to replace `= @AccountId` with `IS @AccountId`? Or do you want something more general?

Comment: In the next steps the @AccountId will be replaced to `NULL`. So finally it will look like `[Account ID] IS NULL`

Comment: Well, it's still straight forward replacement of `= @AccountId` with `IS NULL`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't simply make that replacement as there are some other possible use cases with this. So basically, I need to replace a character that comes before a given word with another character using regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many variations I found the right regex to achieve this.

> =(?=(\s?)+@AccountId)

Explanation,

```
= - matches the character "="
(?=WordToMatch) - Positive Lookahead
\s - matches any whitespace character
? - matches the previous token between zero and one times
+ - matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
```